# Java doClick does not setBackground

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am doing an autonomous code while refreshing things on the gui. (the logic is completely random right now). 
When I call the `button.doClick()` method. It runs like it should have, but inside I have the `button.setBackground(Color.red)` method. 
The problem being it doesn't set the background until the end. Do I have to do things with multiple threads? Thank you

EDIT: CODE ADDED

```
private void jButtonAutoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
  //pick one here, but lets say it is number one
  JB00.doClick();
}
private void JB00ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
   //sends out shot and gets response
   if(response.equals("Hit"){
       JB00.setBackground(Color.red);
   } 
   else{
        JB00.setBackgorund(Color.Blue)
   }
}
```

Everything works when I just click the button from the gui, So I do not think it is an issue with anything in the JB00 method.

Comment: Could you be more clear? Possibly give a code example?

Comment: please post your code. people cant speculate the behvaior without seeing ur code

Comment: _Don't_ block the EDT; _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Yes please post your code so we know what to work with.